# Once file downloaded move it to different location

Tags: powershell

My aim is to wait for a file to download; the user will change hence `%userprofile%` which I cant seem to crack, once file is downloaded id like to move to the root of C.

```
while (!(Test-Path "%userprofile%\downloads\name.exe")) { start-sleep 10 }

 $File = "%userprofile%\downloads\name.exe"
 if (Test-Path $File) {
  Move-Item $File c:\ -Force
}
```

Throughout my shorttime with PowerShell I am struggling with directories

Comment: Have you tried running it with administrator privileges?

Comment: Yes, personally I don't think the %Userprofile%\downloads is incorrect

Comment: PowerShell doesn't really care about what you think personally, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$env:USERPROFILE` variable to determine the user profile and combine the path using the `Join-Path` cmdlet:

```
$filePath = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'downloads\name.exe'

while (-not (Test-Path $filePath)) 
{ 
    start-sleep 10 
}
if (Test-Path $filePath) 
{
    Move-Item -Path $filePath -Destination 'c:\' -Force
}
```